# Cloudant / couch db Two way replication - what prevents recursiveness?

Tags: couchdb, replication, cloudant

We have two cloudant databases say A and B on two separate clusters. We have setup two way replication between these databases, so A->B and B->A.

1) If a document X is updated on A , it gets replicated to B. But this change on B is not replicated again back to A. So it does not get into indefinite recursive cycle. Is this achieved using the revision numbers ? I believe it might be internal to couchdb.

2) We need to figure out by looking at a document in both A and B , that which database actually received the update through API call and which one received the update through replication. Is there a way to figure this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [CouchDB replication protocol](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html) is well defined and makes sure that the replication is done in a reliable manner.
2. CouchDB has no concept of a master. Once synced, all CouchDB instances are identical so it won't be possible to determine which node received the original request. If you need to do this, you probably should reevaluate whether replication is what you really want.